# Open Source Equivalent for Sybase Open Server

Tags: architecture, sybase

Is there any Open source equivalent for Sybase Open Server?

The description for Sybase Open Server in their website

> Using Open Server, customers can develop middle tier server
>   applications that are transparent to the client, looking like Sybase
>   Adaptive Server Enterprise, easing the complexities involved in
>   developing and deploying applications in a multi-tiered Computing
>   environment.
>
> Open Server provides multiple clients and servers access to
>   centralized application logic, alleviating the need to constantly
>   update individual clients. Open Client and Open Server help developers
>   create better applications by making it possible for all elements in a
>   given information system to work together more efficiently and
>   effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Server is an API to mimic a Sybase product (specifically Sybase ASE).  It allows you to write software that looks and acts like Sybase ASE, so that applications that are used to dealing with ASE can interact with it.  Since it's directly tied to the ASE software (and it's expected to be used with ASE somewhere nearby) it's not available in open source.

Comment: Sorry my intended question was is there any Open Source DB providing similar feature!

Comment: Ah, I see.  

Open Server does a lot of things, but the main part is that it provides the DB communications layer (called TDS).  TDS is the protocol (usually inside TCP/IP) that ASE uses to accept queries and return information.  Anything that "talks TDS" can pretend to be an ASE database.

I think what you are looking for is an open source database that publishes it's communications protocol, or better yet, one that has an API so you can use that protocol for your own middleware.